# How does different implementations of message queue persistence layer works?

Tags: c#, queue, persistence, message-queue

I am about to create a very simple queue mechanism for some of our services, the problem i am facing is that i am in need to implement some persistence layer, since messages should not get lost if somebody kicks the power plug on the server.

My first thought was to create a separate tabel for this, and "just" use it as persistence layer, but after reading couple of articles about queues, i found out that this is a very bad idea, since there are quite a lot of inserts and reads to the same table which should lock the table, because 2 instances of the same service should not be able to get same job.

So my question is, which persistence mechanism should i implement?

Comment: Why don't you use [already](http://activemq.apache.org/) [existing](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) [solutions](http://redis.io/)?